# onDragEnd event is not firing in react beautiful dnd

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-beautiful-dnd

Below is my code, onDragEnd event is not firing

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
          {(dropProvided: any, snapshot: any) => (
            <div
              ref={dropProvided.innerRef}
              {...dropProvided.draggableProps}
              style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
            >
              {formOrderItems!.map((item, index) => (
                <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id} index={index}>
                  {(provided: any, snapshot: any) => (
                    <div>
                      <div
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        style={getItemStyle(provided.draggableStyle, snapshot.isDragging)}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </div>
                      {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              ))}
            </div>
```

What I am doing wrong here. onDragEnd event is not firing,

What I am missing here, below is he code snippet on onDragEnd event

```
 class TestOrderInternal extends React.Component<TestOrderInternalProps, {}> {
 constructor(props: TestOrderInternalProps) {
 super(props);
 }

  public onDragEnd = (result: any) => {
  // dropped outside the list
  if (!result.destination) {
  return;
}
......
  };
```

Comment: Can you create a demo of it over codesandbox?

Comment: Did you **debug** it and check? What was the issue coming while debugging?

Comment: did you ever figure it out?